# Spring security oauth2 login / spring cloud gateway sends 302 with XHR

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm developing a SPA application (angular) with a BFF using spring cloud gateway configured as an oauth2 client with spring security and a keycloak server as the authorization server.
I've made a classic configuration of spring security :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().authenticated())
        .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
            .csrf().disable()
            ;
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The Gateway is configured with TokenRelay as a default filter. It works fine.

The problem I get is that when I make a XHR request, to call an API mainly, if no session exists or is expired, the gateway will respond with a redirect to the login page.
This is fine when the request is made using the browser but not with an ajax request as I can't distinguish a 302 because I'm not authenticated from a regular 302.

I know that it's the expected behavior from spring security (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9266). But how can I change this behavior to send at least a 401 for an non authenticated XHR?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue. How you fixed it?

Comment: Hi, I didn't fix it for the moment. I need to try ch4amp solution to see if it works

Answer (score 1):

##### EDIT

My original answer with references to Javascript based web apps (or mobile apps) configured as "public" OAuth2 client and `spring-cloud-gateway` transparent to security was going against [latest recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390). Here is a solution to return the status code from downstream resource servers, behind a gateway configured as an OAuth2 client with `TokenRelay` filter (as wisely done in the question).

The REST APIs behind your gateway should be configured as resource servers and implement their own access control, in which case it would return 401 for unauthorized request to protected resource.

In such case, just `permitAll()` on the gateway:

- if the user session is authorized, the `TokenRelay` will set the `Authorization` header before forwarding the request and the resource server should answer with 2xx
- if the user session is not authorized, then the `TokenRelay` won't set the `Authorization` header before forwarding the request and the resource server should answer with 401

I have a [working sample](https://bff.demo.c4-soft.com/ui/) of a system with an Angular front-end, a Spring REST API configured as stateless resource server and a BFF in between (`spring-cloud-gateway` with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`, `oauth2Login` and the `TokenRelay=` filter). The code source is in [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff).

In this application, the redirection to login does not happen because an unauthorized request to a protected resource: Angular app explicitly triggers this redirection. All routes configured with `TokenRelay` filter are configured with `permitAll()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it doesn't seems to work : I still get a redirect to the login page. As far as I know, isn't the  AccessDeniedHandler called too late in the process for my purpose (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-exceptiontranslationfilter) ? The XHR call is not denied, it is unauthenticated so I should return a AuthenticationEntryPoint that return a 401.

Comment: It may works with the resource-server but my BFF is configured as a client.

Comment: Are you sure that the HTTP status was not returned by a resource-server behind the gateway? I configure gateway to just forward authorization haeder to resource-server and response status from it. Access decision is, in my opinion, better placed where I can unit-test it.

Comment: Well I'm sure because I have 2 resource servers behing the gateway and none of them were running when I made the test. In fact I have implemented the Oauthclient pattern which is described in this article : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-oauth2. So with this pattern, it is the gateway which "generates" the authorization header. It is not sent by the user agent.

Comment: Well, there is a 3rd alternative for gateway OAuth2 configuration this article does not talk about: **be transparent** (do nothing) . In your "client" configuration, what if the "real" client can't login using forms (programmatic client with client-credentials)? What if there are several authorizion-servers to choose from? What if knowing the actual client is important? There are good OAuth2 client libs for all mainstream frameworks, just authorize requests on "real" clients.

Comment: See my updated answer: when configuring oauth2Login, you explicitely ask the gateway to redirect unauthorized users to authorization-server (this is how authorization-code flow starts). Don't do that. Configure your Angular app as OAuth2 client, not the gateway.

Comment: A very interesting answer with valid points! I will respond in several comments.
I would say that my first thought on using the gateway as the client was about security.
When I look at the oauth spec on browser based application (https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-11.html), it seems that the pattern where javascript applications obtain tokens directly is the slightly less secured pattern. The token is stored in the application which is then exposed to token exfiltration. But I agree that there's still the XSS attack that is possible.

Comment: Regarding the drawbacks you pointed :

1/ Session management : I have not experienced yet but I thought I could resolved horizontal scalability using a service like Redis. CSRF is important I agree, I have deactivated only for testing purpose.

2/ In the application I designed, the gateway is a BFF so it has a clear purpose and is dedicated to a specific front end application. In my idea, other clients like an external application would not use this BFF but have another client.

Comment: 3/ if multiple flow need to be supported, it seems that I can register multiple clients within the same gateway with spring security oauth client.

4/ for the last point, to me this is handle by spring security login. I can register multiple clients with different authorization servers. It is up to the user to decide what to use. Even if in my case, I did not intend to offer multiples auth server. And if I did, as I use Keycloak I think it is possible to manage this through Keycloak and not spring security.

Comment: Setting up and maintaining a redis cache for sessions is clearly additional complexity. That's sad for something you can so easily avoid.

Comment: Incoming traffic through the gateway and as direct connection depending on the client will be a challenge to maintain on firewall (you'll have dangerous breaches sooner or later)

Comment: You are thinking of a single Keycloak instance with a single realm. On the last project I worked on, they were two: one for corporate users (local network) and an other one for the public (from the Internet)

Comment: Last, regarding security (as well as scalability), why do you think Google, Facebook, Whatsapp and basically any modern Javascript based app editor authorize requests from the client? If there is no authorization sent with the request, server has to maintain a session. Session can be stolen too and are longer lived than correctly configured access-token. Longer => more consequences for identy usurpation

Comment: Since my original answer and the comments we exchanged (almost a year ago) I shifted on the "BFF configured as OAuth2 client with TokenRelay filter" side of the force and adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, great job @ch4mp.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by replacing the `ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint` configured by `oauth2Login()`.

We can use [`MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.3.x/api/org/springframework/security/web/server/util/matcher/MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher.html) to guess whether a request comes from browser interaction based on `Accept` headers, and delegate to [`RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.3.x/api/org/springframework/security/web/server/authentication/RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint.html) for redirection if so. Delegation is supported by [`DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.3.x/api/org/springframework/security/web/server/DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint.html) which will fall back to a default `401 Unauthorized` response for unmatched requests.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().authenticated())
        .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
        .csrf().disable();

    // Override the default entry point used by oauth2Login
    http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(browserRedirectEntryPoint());
    return http.build();
}

ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint browserRedirectEntryPoint() {
    MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher browserMatcher = 
        new MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    // This avoids wildcard "Accept: */*" headers causing greedy browser match
    browserMatcher.setIgnoredMediaTypes(Collections.singleton(MediaType.ALL));

    ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint redirect = 
        new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint(loginPageUri);
    return new DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint(new DelegateEntry(browserMatcher, redirect));
}
```

You can add or remove criteria to the browser matcher as you see fit (see the [default configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/7ee974445bd09534e6fd5fa4d38cbc2fa6160500/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/web/server/ServerHttpSecurity.java#L4381-L4419) for reference). `401 Unauthorized` is default behavior of `DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint`, but if you prefer to be explicit you could add your own delegate entry to handle XHR requests.